# sqlite3 query keeps failing to insert

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am trying to take the variable generated from cpu usage, but for some reason and no matter what I try the terminal returns a syntax error after `getCpuLoad))` and also the sqlite3 query doesn't effect the table or database in question.

```
def main():
      while True:
        print"CPU usage=%.2f%%" % (getCpuLoad()*100)
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (Date, Cpu) VALUES (?,?)", (today, getCpuLoad))
        time.sleep(INTERVAL)  
      conn.commit()
      conn.close()
```

can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert the *function*, not it's result. Call the function again:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (Date, Cpu) VALUES (?,?)", (today, getCpuLoad()))
```

If `today` is a function as well, you'd need to call that too of course.

Comment: so do i have to call the function to retrieve the results printed from getCpuLoad for insertion into the database or are you saying don't call the function if i want to insert the result of the function

Comment: @user2169708: You *have* to call a function to insert the results of the function.